# How to Add new tr in each table?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

Can anyone please please Help me. I am using laarvel framework. I want to add tr when user click on ADD NEW Service Button. The data is displayed in foreach Loop. 
 [image]
when user click on Add New Service
[image]

here is my Html Code:-

```
enter code here
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
    @foreach($alldata as $data)
    <div class="services-name">
        <h4>{{ $data['name'] }} <button id="{{ $data['id']}}" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-nail getid"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-nail" >
            <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"> &nbsp;Add New Service</i>
            </button>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="table-class">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="append-{{ $data['id'] }}">
                    <tr>
                        <th style="width:33.33%">Services</th>
                        <th style="width:33.33%">Duration</th>
                        <th style="width:33.33%">&pound; Price </th>
                    </tr>
                    @foreach($data['sub_services'] as $subservices)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $subservices['name']}}</td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="service_id[]" value="{{ $subservices['service_id'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="name[]" value="{{ $subservices['name'] }}">
                        <input type="hidden" name="service_is[]" value="{{ $subservices['service_is'] }}">
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="duration[]" placeholder="Duration">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="price[]" placeholder="price">
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach      
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

And here is My modal

```
enter code here
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-nail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            <h4 class="add-cat"> Add Service</h4>
        </div>
        <form class="servicedata" role="form" method="POST" action="Javascript:;">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <span class="col-xs-3 add-cate-model">Add Service</span>
                    <div class="col-xs-8">
                        <input name="name" class="form-control mdl-txt  txtfield m-tb-10" type="text" placeholder="Add Service" >
                        <input type="hidden" name="list_id" value="{{ $listid }}">
                        <input type="hidden" class="service" name="service_id" value="">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary addService">Submit</a>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery Code:-

```
enter code here
$(document).on('click','.getid', function(){
    var serviceid = $(this).attr('id');
     alert(serviceid);
    $('.addService').addClass(serviceid);
    $('.'+serviceid).on('click',function(){
        $('.service').val(serviceid);
        if(flag==1) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "add-category-service",
            data: $('.servicedata').serialize(),
            success:function(resp){
                if($.trim(resp)){
                   $("#append-"+serviceid).append(resp);
                    $('.addService').removeClass(serviceid);
                     $('#myModal-nail').modal('hide');
                } else{
                    alert("error"); return false;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    });
});
```

And My laravel function:-

```
enter code here
ublic function addCategoryService(Request $request){
    if($request->ajax()){
        $data = $request->input();
        //echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); die;
        unset($data['_token']);
        $subservice = new SessionSubService;
        $subservice->name = $data['name'];
        $subservice->list_id = 1;
        $subservice->service_id = $data['service_id'];
        $subservice->service_is = "top";
        $subservice->save();
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'. $data['name'].'</td>
            <input type=hidden name=service_id[] value=' .$data['service_id'].'>
            <input type=hidden name=name[] value=' . $data['name']. '>
            <input type=hidden name=service_is[] value=top>
            <td>
                <div class=form-group>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="duration[]" placeholder="Duration">
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class=form-group>
                    <input class=form-control type=text name=price[] placeholder=price>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>'; die;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you tell what the actual problem is?

Comment: @sam i want to add new tr when user click on Nails button (ADD new SERVICE) and when user click on Hair button(ADD new SERVICE) that particular service will be added on that table. mY jquery code not workinhg properly. Please help me out

Comment: Be more specific about 'not working properly'. The input box seems to popup. What does happen when people enter a service and click submit? Does the service not showup at all, or at the wrong spot or...?

Comment: @RSt i want to display the entered  service in that table where user clcik the Addnew Service button means when user click on Nails button that service would be visible in nails table and vicversa